# Showing part of truncated string every second in Flask / Python

Tags: python, multithreading, flask

I'm building an app in Flask, but I'm very new to it. What I'd like to do is take a string from an external .txt file, return n digits from it, wait an interval of time, then return n + 1 digits, wait another second, then n + 2 digits, etc.

I can get this to work when printing to the terminal, but can't get it to work actually returning in a view. Don't know where I'm going wrong, any help would be very much appreciated.

For now, I'm getting either a hanging page or a "View function did not return a response" and I'm out of ideas

```
@app.route('/')
@app.route('/index')

 def index():


    class RepeatEvery(threading.Thread):
                def __init__(self, interval, func, *args, **kwargs):
                threading.Thread.__init__(self)
                self.interval = interval  # seconds between calls
                self.func = func          # function to call
                self.args = args          # optional positional argument(s) for call
                self.kwargs = kwargs      # optional keyword argument(s) for call
                self.runable = True
            def run(self):
                while self.runable:
                        self.func(*self.args, **self.kwargs)
                        time.sleep(self.interval)
            def stop(self):
                self.runable = False

    counter = 0

    while counter != 5:
        number = str(counter)
        counter += 1
        thread = RepeatEvery(1, truncate, number)
        thread.start()
        thread.join(1)
        thread.stop()


 def truncate(num):
     with open(os.path.join(APP_STATIC, 'file.txt')) as f:
         data = f.read()
         truncated = data[:num]
         return truncated `
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can stream data back to the client by [using a generator](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/patterns/streaming/):

```
from flask import Response

@app.route('/')
def index():
    data = ""
    with open(os.path.join(APP_STATIC, 'file.txt')) as f:
        data = f.read()

    gen = (data[:num] for num in range(1, 6))

    return Response(gen, mimetype="text/plain")
```

Knowing that, it is then possible to add pauses to your generator:

```
from time import sleep

def gen(data):
    for num in range(1, 6):
        yield data[:num]
        sleep(1)
```